# How does one designate the root of a handheld device?

Tags: compact-framework, directory, windows-ce, special-folders, handheld

I need to recursively search a handheld device for any files anywhere on the device that follow a certain pattern (such as "*Platypus*.XML").

To pass the root of the device to my directory traversal method, do I pass "\" or something else?

In Windows Explorer, the device is "J:\" - but I know that can't work, because it won't be mapped to J for everyone.

The device's full name in Windows Explorer is something like:

```
Duckbill (\\LEXINGTON\dev\Xmen\Miguel\Installs) (J:)
```

...but similarly, each person's device will have a different name, so that won't work.

So is the root folder designated with "\" or is there some method I can call to get that designator, something like *Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup* or...???

### UPDATE

More specifically to my situation, if Windows Explorer says the folder in question is "*Computer\Goliath's Device\Application\ccr*", is the following what I need to programmatically designate that folder: "*\Application\ccr*"?

### UPDATE 2

The following code results in a FileNotFound Exception and then a crash of the .exe on the handheld device:

```
string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\\Platypus.exe");

public static string GetFileVersion(string filePath)
{
        const int VERSION_DEPTH = 4;
        var version = NativeFile.GetFileInfo(filePath);
        return version.Version.ToString(VERSION_DEPTH);
}
```

### UPDATE 3

With the following:

```
string serNum = User.getSerialNo();
string clientVer = DuckbillUtils.GetFileVersion("\\Application\\ccr\\Platypus.exe");
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("serial num == {0}; clientVer == {1}", serNum, clientVer));
```

...I get:

*serialnum == ;
clientVer == ;
Win32Exception*

whereas with the following:

```
string clientVer = DuckbillUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\\Application\ccr\Platypus.exe");
```

(other lines of code identical; verbatim string the only difference)

...I get:

*serialnum == ;
clientVer == ;
FileNotFoundException*

### UPDATE 4

I found some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638097/how-can-i-fix-this-path-not-found-error/638120#638120), and based on code from there:

```
string modulePath = this.GetType().Assembly.GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName;
```

...this is what it showed me for my .exe:

*"\Program Files\HHS\HHS.exe"*

...I then tried to examine a "cousin" exe at (in a different subfolder, but share the same grandparent folder):

```
@"\\Program Files\\LocateNLaunch\\LocateNLaunch.exe"
```

...but that gave me nothing from the GetFileVersion() method.

Anyway, the file I *really* want to examine (for its version info) is in, not a folder per se, but what for lack of knowledge will call a "subdevice" (I don't know what the terminology is, but in Windows Explorer the device is divided into "subdevices" or "superfolders" which have folders beneath them). How does one indicate/designate THAT is what you want to access? My .exe is in one "subdevice" and the .exe whose version info I need to read (and possibly replace) is in another "subdevice"...

If this is unclear, here's a scream shot:

[image]

So how can I point my code to that file (HHSetup.exe) beneath the Application subdevice\sscs folder?

### UPDATE 5

With this code:

```
string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\Application\sscs\HHSetup.exe");
```

...I still get an empty string from that call, followed by a Win32Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device name is irrelevant, it's purely a Explorer Shell Extension trick.  On the device itself, the root is always `\`.  All paths must be fully qualified from that root.

I'd recommend doing some testing before getting the native version info.   Something like:

```
if(!File.Exists(path))
{
    // don't try, report an error or whatever
}
else
{
    var version = GetFileInfo(path);
}
```

or

```
var fi = new FileInfo(path);
if(!fi.Exists)
{
    // don't try, report an error or whatever
}
else
{
    var version = GetFileInfo(fi.FullName);
}
```

Comment: What about to navigate to a "subdevice" (or whatever it's called)? Please see Update 4.

Comment: I guess it's called an "internal flash drive"?

Comment: They are simply mounted as folders right on the root.  They are accessed no differently than any other folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in CE, the root of all storage is `\`. See here for details: [Understanding the File System Architecture in Windows CE .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa459155.aspx). In particular:

> The Windows CE .NET file system is a flexible modular design that allows for custom file systems, filters, and a variety of different block device types. The file systems and all file-related APIs are managed by the FileSys.exe process. This module implements the object store and Storage Manager (we'll look into the object store in a little bit) and unifies all of the file systems into a single system under one root, "\". In Windows CE .NET, all files and file systems exist in a single namespace starting from "\" as the root. All files are identified with a unique path from the root in a hierarchal tree.

Devices can be mounted to the root filesystem, and the mount names are identified in the registry, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles`.